# Code reuse (DRY) in procedural drawing?

Tags: javascript, user-interface, d3.js, svg, dry

I am building a workflow tool that renders with d3js. I initially created the tool in an "editor" mode, where users can drag and manipulate nodes and dependencies within a workflow.  Now I am having a hard time rationalizing the proper way to make my current draw procedure support "view" and "edit" modes and stay DRY.

My initial code is basically one long draw procedure:

1. Define JS prototypes
2. Create initial d3js grid (zoom/pan grid)
3. Function(s): Define menu system
4. Function: Draw dependencies (svg groups in d3js)
5. Function: Draw nodes (svg groups in d3js)
6. Get data, iterate & instantiate, iterate and draw dependencies, iterate and draw nodes

Adding switch logic within each of the functions where mode-behavior or SVG structure differs seems like the road to spaghetti-code.

It feels equally wrong to have 3 independent procedures for each mode - but I'm starting to think that having a distinct "draw" procedure for each mode is more flexible way to go about having 3 modes.

Maybe I'm thinkin' about this all wrong. Maybe I should render everything in read-only mode first and then apply any "edit" or "monitor" mode behaviors or visual additions afterwards.

What's the best way to support multiple similar, but different draw procedures in a DRY fashion?

[image: Workflow editor]

Comment: See http://bost.ocks.org/mike/chart/

Comment: stick your code on [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) and see what they say there.

Comment: @RobertLongson, please read a [Guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users). Questions on Code Review needs to have actual working code to be considered on topic.

Comment: After reading the [on-topic guidelines](https://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for [programmers se](https://programmers.stackexchange.com/), maybe it would be on-topic there? I hesitate to say so, because someone else might point out a reason it's not suitable.

Comment: We also have a guide for Programmers: **[What goes on Programmers.SE? A guide for Stack Overflow](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7182/22815)**. This question is asking about design, but does not meet [our requirements for design review](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/6504) as written.

Comment: @holroy I know and he does state that he has working code in the question, although he doesn't actually provide it. I.e. *My initial code is...*

Comment: If OP considers moving code to Code Review, code needs to be included.